# Finding the volume of a sphere in irvine assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have been given an assignment in my assembly class to create a simple program to find the volume of a sphere given a users input, I have to display a message followed by the volume with a fractional amount... I have come up with the following code but unfortunately am stumped by where remainders go and as such how to call them. Anyone have an idea where I'm messing up and how I could fix it?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 
.data
radius byte 0
prompt byte "Please enter the radius of the sphere~ ", 0
volumeMessage byte "The volume of the sphere is~ ", 0
period byte ".", 0
volumeNumber dword 0,  0dh,0ah
volumeFraction dword 0,  0dh,0ah
piMul dword 88
piDiv dword 21

.code
main PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt  
    call WriteString
    call readdec
    mov radius, al

    mul radius
    mul radius

    mul piMul

    div piDiv

    mov volumeNumber, eax
    mov volumeFraction, edx

    mov edx, OFFSET volumeMessage   
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET volumeNumber
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET period
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET volumeFraction
    call WriteDec

    call WaitMsg            
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I mispoke, I am confused as to why when I try to pull the remainder from edx It keeps being the same as the result in eax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Irvine32.asm:

```
;-----------------------------------------------------
WriteDec PROC
;
; Writes an unsigned 32-bit decimal number to
; the console window. Input parameters: EAX = the
; number to write.
```

So instead of:

```
mov edx, OFFSET volumeNumber
call WriteDec
```

you should use:

```
mov eax, volumeNumber
call WriteDec
```

And similarly for `volumeFraction`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it so that its printing out both numbers. Though the fraction is wrong at least its printing out!

Comment: @RickSchlund : If this answer was of use to you and it provided an answer that fixed your problem, good etiquette is to accept the answer. You can learn more about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Michael: Sorry I didn't know how to accept the answer since I had just started using stackoverflow recently, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the sloppy code your program can only process radii smaller than 16.

```
mov radius, al
mul radius
mul radius
```

After the first multiplication result is in AX but the second multiplication will only use AL! Since 16*16 is already to large for the AL register you end up with a very limited range of usable numbers.

Problems continue with the third multiplication. Here because *piMul* is defined as dword the `mul` uses EAX but only AX has a definitve value from the previous code.

```
mul piMul
```

You could define *radius* a dword and write

```
mov  radius, eax
imul eax, radius
imul eax, radius
mul  piMul
div  piDiv
```

Furthermore as Michael said *WriteDec* expects the number itself and not the address to the number. So drop the *OFFSET* tag.